# MariaDB: Periodic copy of data from local database to remote database

Tags: mysql, backup, replication

**I need to periodically copy the outcome of a view on our local database to another remote database.**

I've tried using `mysqldump` which works fine when copying data from tables to tables, but I need to copy the data from either a view or a stored procedure.

As an example I've created a sourcedb and a destinationdb. I need to copy data from the view in sourcedb and append the data in a table at the destinationdb.

Is that possible?

> **Mysqldump:**

```
mysqldump --skip-add-drop-table -uroot -p*** sourcedb sourceview | sed 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g' | mysql -P3306 -uroot -p*** destinationdb
```

> **Error:** 
>  ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 41: Table 'destinationdb.table1' doesn't exist

Comment: Use `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` from the view or in stored procedure. Move output file to remote server and insert the data using `LOAD DATA INFILE` into some table of according structure.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it’s very clearly stated that the target remote database doesn’t have table `destinationdb.table1`. Some of the views required **table1** in the query.

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 41: Table 'destinationdb.table1' doesn't exist
```

In this case, you need to migrate the **table1** as well to the destination database.